# Reference in constructor parameter calls reference's default constructor

Tags: c++

I am using the following classes declaration:

```
class A {
public:
    A(int, float);
    A(const A&);
};

class B {
public:
    B(A&);
protected:
    A a;
};
```

I also set up the following definition for B:

```
B::B(A &a) {
    this->a = a;
}
```

The problem is I have an error on the definition of my `B`constructor, telling me that there is `No matching function for call to A::A()`.

Why does my B constructor tries to create a new A?

If the previous step is needed, why doesn't it call the copy constructor using the reference?

Comment: Does `B` derive from `A`, or does it contain an instance of `A`?

Comment: The code you posted will not attempt to default-construct an `A` in `B`s constructor and will not generate this error. Please, post real code. The code you posted is fake.

Comment: This is not a testcase. It does not reproduce the problem. http://sscce.org

Comment: There is indeed a contained member of type A, I'll add this omission right now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume your `B` has an `A` that needs to be constructed. In your current constructor, your not explicitely specifying an `A` constructor to use. Therefore it tries the default constructor of `A` which does not exist:

Maybe you meant to construct B's A with the reference?

```
class B {
private:
    A _a;
public:
    B(A& a) : _a(a) {}

};
```

Comment: Oh you're right, I was not looking at the right place...
I indeed have a member of type A which needs to be initialized.
My constructors are all public. I just omitted to add the markers, which is now done with the edition of my 1st post.

Comment: What was confusing was also that I was having a definition of the A object contained in B. It was not set in the constructor definition line, but rather in its body. I changed the member definition from `this->a = a` to `B::B(A &a) : a(a)` and now it works... That's probably because the compiler was trying to build the object before filling it up and now it does the second step at the same time. Wild guess